# How to overrite Bootstrap variable --bs-heading-color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

Using Bootstrap theme in wordpress called `BScore` and css compiled by scss I have a file called:

`_bscore_variables.scss` which allows me to override the bootstrap theme variables.

So for example I set the color variables:

```
$gray-100:                        #f8f9fa;
$gray-200:                        #e9ecef;
$gray-300:                        #dee2e6;
$gray-400:                        #ced4da;
$gray-500:                        #adb5bd;
$gray-600:                        #6c757d;
$gray-700:                        #495057;
$gray-800:                        #343a40;
$gray-900:                        #212529;
$black:                           #000;
```

Then I can override the primary secondary etc variables like this in the same file:

```
$primary:                         $red;
$secondary:                       $gray-600;
$success:                         $green;
```

However the headings of the theme I am using are taking their color from a variable called `--bs-heading-color` and when I try to add an override in the file as

`$heading-color: $grey-800` I get an error message saying there was a problem compiling the scss

If I change that line to something like:
`$heading-color: grey` I don't get any compilation error but I don't see the color taking effect in the browser.  If I inspect the element I see the original color setting for the element as `h2 { color: var(--bs-heading-color);}`

Can anyone advise how to overide this variable?

The documentation on bootstrap colors doesn't make any mention of that particular variable or where it comes from.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/colors/#sass-variables

Comment: What is the error you get when you compile it?

Comment: Just looking at the Frontend Wordpress the page fails with the message: ```Something went wrong with the SCSS compiler.```

I'm going to dig into the logs on wordpress to see if I can get any more detail

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

You have to override `$headings-color` not `$heading-color`.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried that and all sass does is override .popover { --bs-popover-header-color: }

Comment: $headings-color override all BS headings color like this:

`color: var(--bs-heading-color);`